In constructions with attributive nouns, which noun are articles applies to—attributive noun or noun being modified?
For example, in "a network name", the article applies to "network" or "name"?

Does this answer your question? Determiners (the, a, some) that come before possessives (book's title, government's decision) help determine that Possessive or the noun after it?

I'm not sure it makes any difference in the specific example a network name, but it may help to note that the indefinite article a here is a determiner. So are this and your, so you might usefully consider the noun phrases this / your network name, where unquestionably this / your attach to the "head noun" name. If they attached to the "noun adjunct" network, it would normally be this network's name or your network's name.

Can you provide more details on why you're asking. There are subtleties when using a determiner with an attributive noun or another multi-word noun phrase, particularly when you're identifying a particular thing, and stress and pitch contour can help. But network name is a well-known compound noun describing a particular, well-defined thing, so it should be straightforward to treat it as a unit.

I think am looking for general rules on using articles with these phrases.

For example, "the organization's car". The can be applied to "organization" meaning any car belonging to the particular organization. Or it can be applied to "car" meaning the particular car belonging to the organization.

Yes, you're correct. In "the organization's car," the determiner "the" can be applied to either. It depends on context. It would unfortunately be hard to give you general rules for such a broad question. However, if you edit your question to include more examples and information or a more specific case, then it might be answerable

IT department worker talking to fellow worker within the company: "Your user password is XYZ". Software house tech support talking to IT department worker: "Your user's password is XYZ".

The article "a" determines the whole noun phrase "a network name", where it marks it as indefinite.

"Organization's" is not an attributive noun in "the organization's car". It's not the same as "the organization car". You seem to be asking two completely different questions.

As above, can you provide a complete example, illustrating the real context with a full sentence? With no qualification, a 'network name' might be a compound noun, the two elements being inseparable.
Separately a 'network' name is a very different thing from a 'personal' or any other type of name.

Since you are referring to the name of the network, the article is applied to "name".
When adding an article to a compound word, the article refers to the last fraction of it. The other word(s) act as adjective(s) to the last word.
Examples:

a network name
the ice cream
a dish soap
a cocker spaniel


In English Language Learners, don't the innocent Learners deserve protection?
I hope 'network name' is obvious even to Learners but the rest aren't at all.
Could 'ice cream' work with 'ice' and 'cream' separated?
Are there soaps specially designed to sit in dishes?
How is 'cocker spaniel' not a compound noun, rather than a phrase using 'cocker' as an adjective describing the noun 'spaniel'?
